# Rendering rotated text to PDF in PhantomJS

Tags: phantomjs

I have a HTML page, which contains several pieces of text that are rotated using the following piece of CSS:

```
.rotate {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
```

When I pull up the page directly in the browser this renders as expected. When I render the page through PhantomJS, it seems to ignore the rotation.

I upgraded to Phantom 2.0.0, but still the same issue.

Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: did you try -webkit-transform?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I tested it with PhantomJS 1.9.18 in a node application.

With `-webkit-transform` and `-webkit-transform-origin` the text on the generated PDF is rotated. Withouth the -webkit prefixes its only rotated when I view it with a browser, not rendered in the pdf.

So you should change your CSS to

```
.rotate {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Phantom JS is based on Webkit. You need to use `-webkit-` prefix for incompatible  css rules.

```
.rotate {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);   
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;   
}
```