# phantomjs - Text transform rotate distort text rotation

Tags: javascript, css, svg, phantomjs

I have a webpage I want to print it, I am using `phantomjs`. My web page has `text` element which need to rotate I am using `transform` and `rotate`. They `rotate` accordingly in browser but When I print there rotation distort.
**Note:I am creating `text`  dynamically.**
so I can not make a `class` referring to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31418265/rendering-rotated-text-to-pdf-in-phantomjs) in this case `rotate` is always `90`.

```
.rotate {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
```

Here is my code

```
g.append("text")
    .each(function (d) {
    d.angle = (d.startAngle + d.endAngle) / 2;
})
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("transform", function (d) {
    return "rotate(" + (d.angle * 180 / Math.PI - 90) + ")" + "translate(" + (innerRadius + 26) + ")" + (d.angle > Math.PI ? "rotate(180)" : "");
})
    .style("text-anchor", function (d) {
    return d.angle > Math.PI ? "end" : null;
})
    .text(function (d) {
    return nameByIndex.get(d.index);
})
    .attr("class", "text");
```

I have tried changing `transform` to `-webkit-transform` in above code, but it giver error

> Uncaught InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '-webkit-transform' is not a valid attribute name.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `WebkitTransform` instead of `-webkit-transform` because The `JavaScript` style names are `WebkitTransformOrigin` and `WebkitTransform`.

Also see [How to set the style -webkit-transform dynamically using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708895/how-to-set-the-style-webkit-transform-dynamically-using-javascript)